# Register windows phone app in google advertising platform

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, admob

I have a free windows phone app and I want to generate revenue from advertising.  I choose google admob to do this task, but when I add my app to admob system, there is no choice for windows phone app. There is only choice for android and iOS. I know that the google admob has the sdk for windows phone 8 but how can I register my app to get Ad ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "unit ID" in your application as a Ad ID.

```
// "MY_AD_UNIT_ID" with your interstitial Ad unit id.


private InterstitialAd objInterstitialAd;

objInterstitialAd= new objInterstitialAd("MY_AD_UNIT_ID");
```

Here is the useful links for the same:

- [Register your app](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2773509)
- [Create an ad unit](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3052638)

Hope it helps

Comment: the problem is when register my app, only choice for android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

Admob doesnot support ad units for Windows phone in some countries. Thats why, it is not showing that option.
PS: not in India as well.